# iOS) How to add a separator at tabbar dividing two tabbarItems

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to customize tabbarItem having footer line meaning it is selected and have a thin line separating two tabbaritems.

But even though searching at stackoverflow, it shows very limit information and low quality.

My tabbar is simple intuitively, having bottom line and a separator.

Comment: @soulshined I know what you mean, but it's different. I know how to customize UITableViewCell but I don't know how to customize tabbarItem. I just need to know where I should code or work with xib or the link for tutorial of customizing tabbarItem.

Comment: I don't know where I do work on so I don't have code